# Adding columns to the table in SQL

Tags: sql, database, sql-query-store

I am adding columns to the table by right clicking on the table -> select Design -> I am adding columns here.

I have successfully executed this code.

But I am still getting invalid column error for those 2 newly added columns. What must be an issue? Any help?

Comment: Show us the table structure and maybe some data.

Comment: Add a screenshot of that message.

Comment: Did you save the table after adding columns?

Comment: I had to refresh the Cache. Its fine now. Thanks :)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And what tool are you using to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refresh cache will solve this issue